# deactivate ' pin to start ' on Application List page when pinning an app via code using C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

i'm creating a windows phone app ,where i've put a button to pin the app to start screen , but when press and hold the app icon on application list screen i find that the pin to start option can be used

```
ShellTile TileToFind = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("MainPage.xaml"));

        // Create the Tile if we didn't find that it already exists.
        if (TileToFind == null)
        {
            // Create the Tile object and set some initial properties for the Tile.
            // The Count value of 12 shows the number 12 on the front of the Tile. Valid values are 1-99.
            // A Count value of 0 indicates that the Count should not be displayed.
            StandardTileData NewTileData = new StandardTileData
            {
                BackgroundImage = new Uri("300.png", UriKind.Relative),
                Title = "apptitle",

                BackTitle = "title",
                BackContent = "testing ",
                BackBackgroundImage = null
            };

            // Create the Tile and pin it to Start. This will cause a navigation to Start and a deactivation of our app.
            ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative), NewTileData);
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Already Pinned");
        }
```

how can i disable the user from pinning the application again from application list screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should understand the difference between Primary and Secondary tiles. What you create from code is a secondary tile, what user pins from context menu is a Primary tile.

Primary tile is always the first one:

```
var primaryTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
```

And keep in mind that primary tile is always exists, even it's not pinned. There is no API to check the primary tile pinned status. So I'd suggest you to remove this feature from your app.

Also some details can be found [here](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/07/21/a-live-tiles-tutorial.aspx).